# SQLite delete old data

Tags: sqlite, sorting

I would like to delete old data from database table. I would just like to keep last 2 records per id. For example I have a table with following records.

```
ID TIME DATA
 1   2   3
 1   3   4
 1   4   5
 2   2   3
 2   3   4
 2   4   5
 2   5   6
```

Result which I would like to make is (it must be sorted by TIME):

```
ID TIME DATA
 1   3   4
 1   4   5
 2   4   5
 2   5   6
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be:

```
select * from tab where (
    select count(*) from tab as t 
    where t.ID = tab.ID and t.TIME >= tab.TIME
    ) <= 2;
```

for more details visit:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/